# Почему git не видит файлы?

Tags: git, github

Есть проект без `.gitignore` в нем лежит несколько независимых модулей. По сути это несколько проектов-микросервисов которые я хочу положить в один репозиторий. Но `git` вместо проектов видит пустые папки, и что еще более странно добавляет их как пустые папки. Вот как это интерпретирует `git` : https://github.com/triodjangopiter/jhipster-microservices

Что происходит? И как мне все-таки залить все это в репозиторий.

[image: Это реальные файлы]

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Comment: А что `git status` говорит?

Comment: @selya говорит все чисто - обновил вопрос.

Comment: Странно... А оно так только в гитхабе, или на локалке ведет себя подобным образом? А файлы все трекаются? Вот, нашел [подобную тему](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382103/git-doesnt-see-new-files-only-the-folder)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Что происходит? И как мне все-таки залить все это в репозиторий.
>
> что еще более странно добавляет их как пустые папки

автор создал [подмодули](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8) примерно так:

```
$ git submodule add url-хранилища каталог
```

каждая такая команда добавляет ключевую информации (включающую, в частности, url хранилища) в файл `.gitmodules`.

каталоги с подмодулями автор добавил в своё хранилище, а вот файл `.gitmodules`, увы — нет.

---

проще всего будет создать новое пустое хранилище и наполнить его так, как вам требуется.

но если очень хочется работать именно с упомянутым хранилищем, то вам надо либо создать валидный файл `.gitmodules`, либо удалить эти четыре подмодуля.

**путь первый — создать**. вам потребуются url-ы тех хранилищ, которые добавил автор. файл `.gitmodules` должен выглядеть примерно так (приведён один подмодуль `blog`, остальные подмодули опишите аналогично):

```
[submodule "blog"]
path=blog
url=сюда впишите url хранилища, которое задумал поместить сюда автор
```

после этого подмодули надо будет инициализировать:

```
$ git submodule update --init
```

**путь второй — удалить**. файл `.gitmodules` тоже придётся создать, но в варианте удаления можно не указывать url-ы (приведён пример только для одного подмодуля, остальные добавьте по аналогии):

```
[submodule "blog"]
path=blog
```

теперь подмодули можно деинициализировать:

```
$ git submodule deinit -f --all
```

удалить уже ненужный файл `.gitmodules`:

```
$ rm .gitmodules
```

и удалить каталоги из хранилища:

```
$ git rm blog ...
```

после чего данное изменение надо закоммитить:

```
$ git commit -m "remove submodules"
```